# Proper way to clean up memory from decoded audio stream (mobile)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am using WebAudio to play music tracks. First I fully decode it with

```
self.ctx.decodeAudioData(xhr.response, function (buffer) {
    this.cache = buffer;
})
```

and save the decoded buffer to some variable for the time when I need to start playing it.

When I want to switch the track, I am cleaning up the audio node with

```
node.source.onended = function (value) {
    node.source = null;
};
```

and the cache with:

`this.cache = null;`

and decode the next track to the same variable.

The problem is if I switch track several times is quick succession (like 3-4 3min tracks), iOS-based mobile browsers just reload the page since, as it seems, I'm using all available memory for the tab. While I'm using only one buffer variable, I guess garbage collector does not free memory of audio buffers that I'm not using anymore.

Any ideas how to improve the implementation?

Comment: Are you *sure* you've freed *every* reference to the memory, including the `xhr` object? Can you make an [mcve] to showcase the issue.

Comment: As for example - it might be problematic tbh. Mostly because I'll need to create separate minimalistic example that will show the problem. And it's not that you can do on the fly tbh. I'll try to this evening.

Comment: As for the reference to memory - we have 3 of them as I see:
1. Cache - we're cleaning it
2. node.source.buffer - we can't directly clear the buffer, but we do clear the node.source variable. So it should take care of the problem.
3. xhr object. Request is done in a private function and xhr.response is passed to self.ctx.decodeAudioData. Do we need additional cleanup for this case?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out - problem was with the garbage collector. It takes up to 20-30 seconds for previous memory to truly clean up. So solution that worked for me - I start playing track and disable the ability to switch to another track for 30 seconds. It's enough time for memory to clean everything up.